# Can we define Möbius functions on preordered sets?

Tags: order-theory

(From Rota's paper): Let $P$ be a locally finite poset.  The *incidence algebra* of $P$ is the set of all real-valued functions $f$ of two variables $x$ and $y$ in $P$ with the property that $f(x, y) = 0$ if $x\not\le y$.
The sum of two such functions $f$ and $g$, as well as multiplication by scalars, are defined as usual. The product $h = fg$ is defined as follows: $$h(x, y) = \sum_{x\le z \le y} f(x,z) g(z,y).$$
The familiar delta function $\delta(x, y)$ is the identity for this product.
The *zeta function* $\zeta(x,y)$ is defined to be $1$ if $x \le y$ and $0$ otherwise.

We define the inverse $\mu(x, y)$ of the zeta function by induction over the number of elements in the segment $[x, y]$. First, set $\mu(x,x) = 1$ for all $x$ in $P$. Suppose now that $\mu(x, z)$ has been defined for all $z$ in the open segment $[x, y)$. Then set $$\mu(x,y) = -\sum_{x\le z<y}\mu(x,z).$$
Then $\mu$ is inverse to $\zeta$ and it is called the *Möbius function* of $P$.
The importance of the Möbius function is the following fundamental inversion formula:
$$g(x) = \sum_{y\le x} f(y) \implies f(x) = \sum_{y \le x}g(y)\mu(y,x)$$
where $f$ is any real-valued function on $P$ which vanishes under some $p$ in $P$.

**Question.** Can we define the Möbius function if $\le$ is not antisymmetric? This is vague, because what do I mean by "the Möbius function"? I mean something satisfying the inversion formula. The proof of the inversion formula uses the $\zeta$ function, so I guess the answer depends on whether $P$ (now just a preordered set) admits a $\zeta$ function...

**Update.** Qiaochu's answer explains that the $\zeta$ function always exists for a finite category, but that it may not always be invertible in the algebra. So, how is $\le$'s antisymmetry being used in proving the invertibility of $\zeta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the Möbius function in much more generality than this: $P$ can be replaced by a category.

Let me work with a finite category $C$ for simplicity. Then it has a "category algebra" $\mathbb{Z}[C]$ given by the free vector space on its morphisms, where the product of two morphisms is their composition if that is well-defined and zero otherwise. This is a very general construction:

- If $C$ is a finite poset then this recovers the incidence algebra.
- If $C$ is a finite group regarded as a one-object category then this recovers the group algebra.
- If $C$ is the free category on a finite quiver with no directed cycles then this recovers the quiver algebra.

The zeta function in $\mathbb{Z}[C]$ is the sum of every morphism in $C$. It is not always invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[C]$ (unlike the case where $P$ is a poset), but when it is, its inverse is the Möbius function of $C$.

Tom Leinster has written several papers about this; see, for example, [this blog post](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/05/mbius_inversion_for_categories.html).

Comment: Cool! I had a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#In_category_theory to see just how preorders and posets can be viewed as categories. How is antisymmetry expressed categorically? Specifically, if $C$ encodes a poset and $D$ a preordered set, then in what way do $C$ and $D$ differ? My guess would be that every morphism in $C$ that is invertible is actually an identity morphism, whereas $D$ (possibly) contains distinct, isomorphic objects.

Comment: @Unit: for a preorder regarded as a category, antisymmetry is equivalent to the condition that isomorphic objects are equal; that is, it's the condition that the category is skeletal (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton).